# Does GSM use direct routing or indirect routing?

Tags: routes, gsm

I am studying the routing mechanism for GSM, and I came across this set of notes (looks like many colleges adapted from them):

[https://www.ida.liu.se/~TDDD66/timetable/2017/TDDD66_2017_05_mobility.pdf](https://www.ida.liu.se/%7ETDDD66/timetable/2017/TDDD66_2017_05_mobility.pdf)

In Slide 18, it describes how to use indirect routing to route the calls. However, in Slides 21-22, the method described for routing calls when the device moves (handoffs) from one MSC to another is clearly a direct routing mechanism (as shown in Slide 14). So is GSM supporting both kinds of routing? Or is direct routing used when there is a handoff to another MSC?

Answer (score 1):

The handoff case is referring to active sessions or calls - i.e. when a user is on a call and moved from an area covered by one radio mast and base station to another.

If the base stations are both connected to the same MSC then the handoff is just between the base stations. If they are connected to different MSC's then the handoff is also between the MSC's.

Comment: +1 for the 2 handoff cases, though it does not address the first question, which is rather on which kind of routing is used in Slide 21, and which kind of routing is supported by GSM. Is the word "not" instead of "bot" in the 2nd paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the mechanism in Slide 21 is still indirect routing (and in fact GSM and mobile IP only support indirect routing), since the correspondent's call is still forwarded by the Home MSC to the remote device (which may have to pass through the anchor MSC and a chain of other MSCs that the remote device has visited).

If it were direct routing, then the home MSC should tell the correspondent the MSC the remote device is now at (with best effort, since this information can be outdated as the remote device may be continuously moving).